# How to work around the terrible API (JVM-wide system properties) of JavaMail?

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-mail, attachment, application-server

**Situation**

We have multiple applications that are deployed on a single JBoss EAP 7 instance. The applications are using the JavaMail API for mailing. For one application, where recipients primarily receive mails in Microsoft Outlook, we had to change the JavaMail property `mail.mime.encodeparameters` to `false`, because Outlook doesn't handle RFC 2231 very well.

**Problem**

Primary problem now is how JavaMail API is designed to use system properties for the MIME configurations. An example of this is the class `javax.mail.internet.ParameterList`, where the following code is found:

```
private static final boolean encodeParameters =
    PropUtil.getBooleanSystemProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters", true);
```

Because of this, we currently set the property in our application bootstrap process, like:

```
System.setProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters", "true");
```

To me, this is not a satisfactory solution as system properties are JVM-wide and therefore affect all application deployments on the same application server! This also prevents using different configurations per application.

**Questions**

- How can I work around these limitations of the JavaMail API in my situation?
- Is there an alternative (and better) API or mail framework?